# React native text input onblur event gets called on its own, preventing keyboard input to be processed

Tags: react-native

trying to build an OTP input screen. From what I read, it can be achieved by hiding the `TextInput` component and displaying the inputted text in views. I have shared a basic Expo snack link. The text input is not taking the values I press on the keyboard. here is the expo link - https://snack.expo.dev/oD72PI5Xch. Can someone help me with what I am doing wrong?

Another issue I have noticed is that the keyboard doesn't show up if I press the back button and then again press the `<Text>` component from where I have called the `onPress` to call `focus()` on the `TextInput`. It will come up if I press the back button and then press the Text component only once. If I again close it using the back button, after that the keyboard stops coming up.

Below is the console log output based on the logging statements I have in the code snack (my actions are marked with >>>>>) -

```
1>>>>> App opens up
text input onfocus called
text input onblur called
keyboard did show
2>>>>> App stabilizes
3>>>>> I press the back button
keyboard did hide
4>>>>> I press the text component
calling focus
keyboard did show
5>>>>> I press the back button
keyboard did hide
6>>>>> I keep pressing the text component
calling focus
calling focus
calling focus
calling focus
calling focus
calling focus
```

I think the issue might be before the 2>>>>> part. The `TextInput`'s `onBlur` is already called. That might be the reason why it is not taking keyboard inputs. Also, even after calling focus, the `onFocus`  logging is absent, meaning that the text input never came into focus. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance :)

And if you solve this, please help me out with the issue of keyboard not appearing on pressing the `Text` component multiple times (6>>>>> part of the console output).

Answer (score 0):

I don't clearly understand what are you trying to do by giving 0 height and width to TextInput, If you are trying to create an OTP input field you can simply use any third-party libraries like [react-native-otp-input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@twotalltotems/react-native-otp-input) or try to use code from this existing [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@mdmoin/otp-input?session_id=snack-session-45GVESXWi)